# How state of a react hook must update if it has Map?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have multiple(more than 15) `div` tags as tiles. I need to emphasis each one if mouse hover on it. So each tag has `onMouseEnter/Leave` functions as bellow.

```
<div
    key={key}
    onMouseEnter={onMouseEnter(key)}
    onMouseLeave={onMouseLeave(key)}
>
    ...
</div>
```

Also I put each tiles key in a `Map` data structure.

```
const onMouseEnter = key => {
    return function() {
        const newIsHover = new Map(isHover)
        newIsHover.set(key, true)
        setIsHover(newIsHover)
    }
}

const onMouseLeave = key => {
    return function() {
        const newIsHover = new Map(isHover)
        newIsHover.delete(key)
        setIsHover(newIsHover)
    }
}
```

Since component is hook it put its state in a `useState`.

```
const [isHover, setIsHover] = useState(new Map())
```

What is happening here:

- Always I enter a tile: `onMouseEnter` function called and its key added to map (as expected)
- When I leave a tile: always `onMouseLeave` called but sometimes key is removed (as expected) and tile turned back to its normal shape but sometimes it does not(**problem is here**, in this situation map updated at `setIsHover` in `onMouseLeave` but it does not changed in the component!).

I think map updated as expected but when I move on new tile it does not understand that yet. So it overwrite it with what it has.

**PS:** example [added](https://codesandbox.io/s/tiles-vb2ec). Move between tiles with high speed!

Comment: What are you using for keys? Array index? Please include entire component code.

Comment: @DrewReese just integers. entire code is too long. I will add my suggestion at the end of Q

Comment: If code is long, try getting a running codesandbox up that reproduces your issue and share *that* here instead. Also, curious as to why not try CSS for the hover state (presuming all you are doing is applying style, but perhaps you do more?).

Comment: Can you please share that how you creating `key` for the map?

Comment: @ZainUlAbideen `keys` are db keys. what I see here is sometimes(when I move on another tile) in `onMouseLeave` key is removed but in new tile we add new key in state map which has previous key as well!!!

Comment: So there might be a case that a tile can have more than on key, which causing the issue. check if this line `newIsHover.delete(key)` returns true whenever you leave mouse pointer from tile?

Comment: @DrewReese code [added](https://codesandbox.io/s/tiles-vb2ec). Move between tiles, just one tile at the moment must be red.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you using a map datastructure? since this UI effect can obviously be achieved without the map data structure, by just using css or your mouse events.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like the class-based components, calls to update state are asynchronous and get queued up. Try using functional state updates to ensure these queued-up updates correctly update the previous state. This should fix race conditions between quick successive `setIsHover` calls with the same key.

*Notice if you move slowly enough between tiles they correctly highlight and unhighlight, but more quickly (like a swipe) and 2 or more can get stuck until you again slowly exit the tile.*

```
const onMouseEnter = key => {
  return function() {
    setIsHover(prevIsHover => {
      const newIsHover = new Map(prevIsHover);
      newIsHover.set(key, true);
      return newIsHover;
    });
  }
}

const onMouseLeave = key => {
  return function() {
    setIsHover(prevIsHover => {
      const newIsHover = new Map(prevIsHover);
      newIsHover.delete(key);
      return newIsHover;
    });
  }
}
```

[image: Edit tiles-good state update]

**But I should note** that this is a lot of leg work for simply applying some component styling, especially hovering. It could more simply be achieved using CSS.

tileStyles.css

```
.tile {
  background-color: lightgray;
  border: 3px solid black;
  height: 100px;
  line-height: 100px;
  margin: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100px;
}

.tile:hover {
  border-color: red;
}
```

tile.jsx

```
import React from "react";
import { withStyles } from "@material-ui/core";

import "./tileStyles.css";

const styles = {
  container: { display: "flex", width: "600px", flexWrap: "wrap" }
};

const Tiles = ({ classes: { container }, tiles }) => {
  return (
    <div className={container}>
      {tiles.map((tl, key) => {
        return (
          <div className="tile" key={key} name={key}>
            hi
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
};

export default withStyles(styles)(Tiles);
```

The normal *and* hovered styles are applied together (at the same time) and CSS/html will manage when it hovered or not. The component no longer requires event listeners and doesn't need to maintain internal state.

[image: Edit tiles]

**Explanation**

> what means "...calls to update state are asynchronous and get queued up."?

When you call `this.setState` or a `useState` update function the update doesn't happen synchronously right then and there, but they are queued up during the current render cycle and [batch](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous) processed in the order in which they were queued. Perhaps [this demo](https://codesandbox.io/embed/muddy-hooks-2rtbk?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&module=%2Fsrc%2FApp.js&theme=dark) will help illustrate what happens. What confounds this issue is the fact that event processing is also asynchronous, meaning that, when events occur their registered callbacks are placed in the event queue to be processed.

Comment: Thanks. Tiles are simplified example to understand what does happens in updating the state. Could you please describe more first part of your answer. I see when I move with high speed between tiles problem occurs but I cannot understand why

Comment: what means *"...calls to update state are asynchronous and get queued up."*?

Comment: @BonjeFir Tried addressing your question in answer.

Comment: Good example and explanation, thanks. Now I am thinking this makes coding very hard/Challenging. Every time we want update state there is a question: *can updating in this way make issue?* I am afraid of complex situations which problem does not appear easily... (in setState there was a rule of thumb: we use callback if we want update using previous state. But in my example it updated in a function just once and after that another function as the same...)

Comment: Previously I think it perfomes all updates in a function asynchronously. I think batch process of (all) updates make job very hard to handle for react(as consistency point of view)! :)